# How to use ng-repeat in different rows

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a grid of two columns for my ionic app so that it prints only two `x` in a row but can not find a way to do it with ng-repeat. Here is what I am trying to do

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="x in ['0','1','2','3','4']">
  <div class="col">
    <span>{{x}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span>{{??}}</span> // what should go here?
  </div>
</div>
```

What I expect to do is

```
 <div class="row" >
     <div class="col">
      <span>0</span>
     </div>
     <div class="col">
      <span>1</span>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" >
      <div class="col">
       <span>2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
       <span>3</span>
      </div>
      </div>
<div class="row" >
      <div class="col">
       <span>4</span>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: That is bad practice if you can do it unless if you can map the string array to an array of an object.

Comment: split you array and use |limitTo: filter

Comment: @AbdElrahmanTelb This is a sample array I am actually getting response from an API

Comment: @AbdElrahmanTelb Can you plz elaborate in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it something like this.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'];
  $scope.itemCount = Math.ceil($scope.items.length / 2);
  $scope.counts = new Array($scope.itemCount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" />

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="count in [].constructor(itemCount) track by $index">
      <div class="col">
        <span>{{items[$index* 2] }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <span>{{items[$index* 2 + 1]}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here what you can test

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="x in array |limitTo:2">
  <div class="col">
    <span>{{x}}</span>
</div>
```

if you wanna make another ng-repeat you can slice the number you iterate form array and reassign it.

you can make use of this example [LimitTo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zA1Euilh6CwzjlGstqMn?p=preview)

Comment: It did not completely resolved my question but helpful

Comment: @sam check the example it may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

In your controller:

```
$scope.myList = ['0','1','2','3','4'];
```

Then in your template:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="x in myList" ng-if="$index % 2 === 0">
   <div class="col" ng-if="$index < myList.length">
     <span>{{x[$index]}}</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col" ng-if="$index + 1 < myList.length">
     <span>{{x[$index + 1]}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should map your array into list of arrays (better in controller) and make nested ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="col in [['0','1'],['2','3'],['4']]">
  <div ng-repeat="x in col">
    <span>{{x}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this with bootstrap and a class="col-sm-6" like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="x in ['0','1','2','3','4']">
    <span>{{x}}</span>
</div>
```